# What do we call a style where we read or analyze something by approaching it first from left to right and then from right to left alternatively?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do we call a style where we read or analyze something by approaching it first from left to right and then from right to left or top to bottom followed by bottom to top alternatively?
Suppose there is a text written (list etc.) in multiple columns, and someone first reads one column top to bottom and the one immediately following it bottom to top and so on. Another kind of scenario may be scanning a line first left to right and then right to left.

Comment: Ancient writing that is alternate L-R and R-L is called **boustrophedon**, meaning that it's like an ox ploughing a field. I don't know of any other examples of such a style.

Comment: Wikipedia has several examples (and related uses of the word): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boustrophedon

Comment: @KateBunting +1 Great find.

Comment: "... class Snake-DREC of languages recognized by deterministic Wang automata directed by **boustrophedonic scanning** strategies" (Deterministic recognizability of picture languages with Wang automata, https://www.thefreelibrary.com/Deterministic+recognizability+of+picture+languages+with+Wang+automata-a0243042770)

Comment: "BOUSTROPHEDONIC A variant of linear scanning, in which the direction of the scan is reversed on alternate grid lines." http://www.geoapi.org/2.2/javadoc/org/opengis/coverage/grid/SequenceType.html

Comment: aka byte-offset scanning http://www.geoapi.org/2.2/javadoc/org/opengis/coverage/grid/SequenceType.html#BOUSTROPHEDONIC